# Any FLOSS Monte-Carlo package for reactor physics?

Tags: nuclear-physics, simulations, software

Any [FLOSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software) Monte-Carlo package for reactor physics? Are there any Free and Open Source software packages for nuclear reactor processes simulation? Maybe, something similar to [MCNP](http://mcnp.lanl.gov/)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [software recommendations](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3980/should-we-allow-software-questions-take-3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenMC ([github](https://github.com/mit-crpg/openmc))

> The OpenMC project aims to provide a fully-featured Monte Carlo particle transport code based on modern methods. It is a constructive solid geometry, continuous-energy transport code that uses ACE format cross sections. The project started under the Computational Reactor Physics Group at MIT.

You can find more background information in this paper ([ScienceDirect](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0306454912003283))